# shebang python отказано в доступе

Tags: python, linux, python-3.6, manjaro

При попытке запустить файл из терминала при помощи shebang пишет "bash: ./name_file.py: Отказано в доступе"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
param = {}
param['key'] = 'trnsl.1.1.20190210T160352Z.c4ca9f9e73e03cc6.831c24e2dfe9e92031dc1537982d711545adf409'
param['text'] = 'some text for translate'
param['lang'] = 'en-ru'
URL = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate'

resp = requests.get(URL, params=param)
print(resp.statment)
```

Comment: Добавьте код текстом.

Comment: Добавил код, но это не играет роли так с любым скриптом, покрайней мере на питоне, просто привел в пример первый попавшийся

Comment: попробуйте использовать другой shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: У вас небось раздел примонтирован с опцией noexec?

Comment: так и есть) спс)

Comment: Зря отметили этот вопрос какт дубликат, сравните их с приведенным вопросом оригиналом, там вопрос стоял, как сделать файл исполняймым в linux у меня же вопрос стоит почему при всех выполненых услових, файл не запускается, я получил ответ чуть выше и по тегам это разные впросы если что

Comment: в ответе написано **в том числе** и про опцию монтирования noexec, и про другие **частные** случаи. так что тот, кто найдёт ваш вопрос, перейдя по ссылке «дубликат», может обнаружить и **свой** частный случай. потому отметка «дубликат» — полезна для базы знаний, которой является данный сайт. // p.s. ну и, собственно, ошибка-то и в данном вопросе, и в «дубликате» — одна и та же: permission denied.